# Is there some way to save objects to disk in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm hunting for a bug, and it would be really helpful if I could dump the contents of the objects my Locals Window to a file so that I could compare it in Notepad++ with another object record that works correctly. The problem is this: we are not sure if there is a bug in code or a discrepancy in the record.

Is there some way to save a object/variable to disk?

I found [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4f15c2aa-58f1-4323-b0f5-a2663142cd51) extension, but sadly it is only for VS 2010, and I have 2012.

Comment: As a side note, the extension you found is basically just a zip file, you can change the extension to .zip, extract the contents, chance the version to 11 in the vsix file inside (it's xml), rezip, change the extension back and install into 2012. This doesn't always work, but it's worth a shot and may save you some time.

Comment: That's an excellent idea! I was able to convert the plugin, but it just crashes VS when I click on it in the menu.

Comment: Ah worth a go anyway, I had the same problem with MVVM in a Box, ended up installing 2010!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [**ObjectDumper**](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper) extension.  It's also available as a NuGet package.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party but I created a Visual Studio extension called Object Exporter that does exactly what you're looking for. It will export any object in your debugging windows (currently only limited to the locals window) to JSON, XML or CSharp object initialization code.

Here's the extension: [**Visual Studio Marketplace > Object Explorer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter)

And here's an accompanying blog post: [**Exporting Objects from the Visual Studio Debugger**](https://www.omarelabd.net/exporting-objects-from-the-visual-studio-debugger/)

Answer (score 1):

The [sources](http://barad-dur.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/ExportLocals.zip) of the Export Locals extension made available for download by the author at 
http://barad-dur.nl/net/export-locals/ so you should be able to convert it to VS2012 easily.

Answer (score 1):

I work at OzCode. It's a debugging extension for Visual Studio and we've been working on a feature that exports instances as XML, json or C# code for a future version.
You can download the early access preview from [Visual Studio's marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeValueLtd.OzCode).
It's a commercial grade solution which enable exporting large amount of data - quickly.

[image: choosing eport format]

I suggest you try it out - once you install OzCode using *Export* is just a matter of opening the DataTip window and choosing "Export".

[image: Exporting image]

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Immediate Window and type object name. It'll print out the simple properties and their values. It does not handle properties that are objects well, though.

Alternatively, you could use JSON serializer to serialize it and print it out in debug console.

Comment: I know how to view the objects in the Immediate Window. I need to persist those values somehow so that I can compare them to another instance of the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experimentation with Log4Net and ObjectDumper to dump objects.

Check out my blog post: [Logging Complete Objects with Log4Net](http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/12/logging-complete-objects-with-log4net.html)

Basically you create your own IObjectRenderer, configure it, and then you can simply log.Debug(yourObject)

```
public class Log4NetObjectLogger : IObjectRenderer
    {
        public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
        {
            var ex = obj as Exception;

            //if its not an exception, dump it. If it's an exception, log extended details.
            if (ex == null)
            {
                //by default log up to 10 levels deep.
                ObjectDumper.Write(obj,10,writer);
            }
            else
            {
                while (ex != null)
                {
                    RenderException(ex, writer);
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                }
            }
        }

        private void RenderException(Exception ex, TextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Type: {0}", ex.GetType().FullName));
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Message: {0}", ex.Message));
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Source: {0}", ex.Source));
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("TargetSite: {0}", ex.TargetSite));
            RenderExceptionData(ex, writer);
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("StackTrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace));
        }

        private void RenderExceptionData(Exception ex, TextWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ex.Data)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value));
            }
        }
    }
```